# Как в Heroku пользоваться PostgreSQL компонентом?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, datagrip

Решил на Heroku разместить проект и столкнулся с рядом проблем по неопытности. Все эти проблемы связаны исключительно с БД.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне подключиться из вне к БД? Пытаюсь прописать данные для подключения (которые даны на странице компонента) в DataGrip и в ответ получаю якобы запрет на авторизацию. На лицо проблема, связанная с файлом pg_hba.conf (нужно прописать в нем мой IP судя по всему). Верно? Но где лежит этот файл, ведь по дефолтным путям (в дефолтных каталогах) я его не нашел, да и поиск `find / -name pg_hba.conf` мне ничего не дал...

В общем и целом расскажите мне, пожалуйста, как вы работаете с БД в Heroku? Все что я пока освоил по этой теме - это то, как делать миграцию:

```
heroku run rake db:migrat
```

Второй способ через:

```
heroku run bash
```

Но этого мало. Я привык, что всегда могу открыть DataGrip и быстро что-то подкорректировать (записи, а не таблицы). Особенно когда идет разработка.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: На Heroku Postgres вам не нужно лезть в `pg_hba.conf`, потому что он уже настроен для удалённого доступа, это ж DBaaS; а вы ранее работали только с локальными инстансами. И поскольку это DBaaS, он работает только по SSL, чтобы не передавать сырые данные по чужим каналам и удостоверяться, что удалённый сервер именно тот, кем представляется. Так что проблема либо в DataGrip, либо в том, как вы разобрали URL на данные для входа, о чём в вопросе ни слова.

Comment: @D-side ну я вводил данные как по отдельности, так и использовал URL, скопированный с сайта. Результат одинаковый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

зайдите в ваш dashboard heroku, выберите ваш проект, поcле чего выберите вкладку recources и откройте Database Credentials. Там будут все необходимые данные для коннект к БД.

Также необходимо в настройках коннекта к БД во вкладке advanced прописать следующее `ssl - true` и `sslfactrory - org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

Comment: Как я и написал - `Пытаюсь прописать данные для подключения (которые даны на странице компонента) в DataGrip и в ответ получаю якобы запрет на авторизацию.`

Comment: Пытаюсь авторизоваться как по ссылке, так и стандартным способом.

Comment: что собою являет "якобы запрет на авторизацию"?

Comment: вот скриншот: https://habrastorage.org/files/4ef/ce0/ade/4efce0ade95f4e7e906bdcbf2c6b7fe3.png

Comment: Ввожу пароль, нажимаю на "ОК" и снова вылезает это же окно. На локалке лечил это тем, что прописывал свой IP в файл pg_hba.conf.

Comment: у вас в настройках коннекта в advanced ssl включен?

Comment: До этого включал. Появляется окно с ошибкой: `SSL error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

Comment: в `sslfactrory`  указано `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`?

Comment: Отлично. Вы прекрасны. Добавьте это в ответ. Нужно в `ssl` прописать `true` и в `sslfactrory` прописать `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`.

Comment: @Colibri вы же понимаете, что сейчас забиваете большой болт на SSL вообще, да?

Comment: @D-side да, я подозревал это (из названия метода). Но у меня проект по сути для демонстрации (разработка). Но а вообще, как было бы правильно сделать? Опять же, повторюсь, на других серверах я прописывал свой IP в pg_hba.conf и это решало проблему с авторизацией...

Comment: @Colibri похоже, что беда именно в DataGrip и/или JDBC, а не в Heroku Postgres. Может, CA-бандл старый. Но как правило, лезть чем-то таким в серверную базу вообще не нужно.

Comment: @D-side хм. Ну у меня актуальная версия, лицензия. Никуда в настройки глубоко не лез. Использовал чисто "запустил -> добавил бд -> управление таблицами, триггерами и прочим".

Answer (score 0):

По проблеме [подключения DataGrip к Heroku PostgreSQL написали хелп](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/how-to-connect-to-heroku-postgres.html)